# Unable to Launch “Xfce4-terminal” on boot

Tags: xfce, autostart

I would like to Launch "Xfce4-terminal" on boot using Xfce desktop, Xrdp-client, and Centos.

I tried creating a .desktop file under .config/autostart and also tried to set the xfce4-terminal on login from the xfce4 desktop settings as well but still I am unable to launch the terminal on boot.

did the following from the Sessions and startup app from the desktop.

```
----
.config/autostart/xfce4-terminal.desktop

[Desktop Entry]

Encoding=UTF-8

Version=0.9.4

Type=Application

Name=xfce4-terminal

Comment=Terminal

Exec=/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal

OnlyShowIn=XFCE;

RunHook=0

StartupNotify=false

Terminal=false

Hidden=false
----
Kindly advise
```

Comment: `RunHook` isn't a valid entry for Desktop entry. Also, are you using CentOS?

Comment: yes, I am using centos 8.1 .. and when I do it from the desktop , this entry came up in the backend (Sessions and Startup ) option

Comment: Unfortunately CentOS is off-topic here. You can post CentOS related questions on [unix.se]. By the way, try removing `RunHook` line from the Desktop entry.